# Git push rejected after pull

Tags: git

I've performed the following steps in git:

```
git stash
git pull origin develop
git stash apply
git commit -a -m 'da de da'
git push origin develop
<correct local date>
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="`date`" git commit --amend --date "`date`"
git pull origin develop
git push origin develop
```

All the pushes gave this error:

```
 ! [rejected]        develop -> develop (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to '<details>:/var/git/mygagenet'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
```

How do I correct this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the error message:

> To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected

tells you why the push was rejected - it doesn't just add new commits on top of the existing ones (which Git calls a "fast-forward update"), but it changes commits you've already pushed. In this case, the `git commit --amend` on your most recent commit has changed that commit.

You can force the push to happen by using

```
git push --force origin develop
```

But if this is a remote branch that other people are using, check with them before you use `git push --force` on the branch, as they may have already done work on this branch with the existing commits.

Comment: Thanks, but I realised I'm being an idiot. I forgot to check I'm on the correct branch :(. Will close the question.

Comment: No worries, glad you found the solution you needed.